# Using Environment Variables with SysV Centos6

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, sysv

I have a Spring Boot application that I installed as a service in *SysV*, so I created a Symbolic link in /etc/init.d/myapp to /home/myuser/app.jar.

Then I start my application in this way:

```
service app start --spring.config.location=application.properties
```

Inside my application.properties I expect an environment variable, see:

```
app.info.version=${APP_VERSION}
```

I always execute `export APP_VERSION=1` before start my service but ${APP_VERSION} is always empty. Then I tried to execute manually in this way:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=application.properties
```

And everything works fine, the environment variable is configured as I expected.

Any tips how can I use environment variables in SysV with Spring Boot service ?

Answer (score 0):

are you able to print the variable using echo command?

```
echo $APP_VERSION
```

Comment: Yes, the value is not empty.